# Why capistrano check non existence of rbenv directory?

Tags: testing, capistrano

I get following message when I run `cap production deploy` in capistrano 3.

```
DEBUG [5021b4ce] Running /usr/bin/env [ ! -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ] on example.com
DEBUG [5021b4ce] Command: [ ! -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ]
DEBUG [5021b4ce] Finished in 0.853 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

This is `rbenv` part in `config/deploy.rb`.

```
set :rbenv_type, :system # or :user, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p451'
set :rbenv_path, '/usr/local/rbenv'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value
```

I thought `Capistrano` should check existence of `rbenv` directory.
Why the command is `[ ! -d #{rbenv_dir}]`, instead of `[ -d #{rbenv_dir}]`?